# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/Credentials error

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I have started `fitnesse rest api testing`. I am only 3 days old to it. I am able to run on `localhost 80`. But it showed few error to me, there were few `jar` files missing.

I am still getting below error.

List of jar I have added:

1. `httpclient-4.0.jar`
2. `log4j-1.2.16.jar`
3. `slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar`
4. `slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar`
5. `smartrics-RestClient-2.1.jar`
6. `xstream-1.4.8.jar`
7. `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar`

```
__EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/Credentials
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.PartsFactory.buildRestClient(PartsFactory.java:61) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.configRestClient(RestFixture.java:1167) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.initialize(RestFixture.java:873) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.doTable(RestFixture.java:385) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction.methodInvoke(DefaultInteraction.java:80) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.callMethod(MethodExecutor.java:44) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:31) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.findAndInvoke(MethodExecutor.java:57) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.FixtureMethodExecutor.execute(FixtureMethodExecutor.java:20) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.getMethodExecutionResult(StatementExecutor.java:126) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.call(StatementExecutor.java:104) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.instructions.CallInstruction.executeInternal(CallInstruction.java:35) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:29) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:83) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:84) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:77) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:56) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:42) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:186) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:194) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:156) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:77) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:57) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.PartsFactory.buildRestClient(PartsFactory.java:61) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.configRestClient(RestFixture.java:1167) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.initialize(RestFixture.java:873) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.doTable(RestFixture.java:385) [smartrics-RestFixture-4.0.jar]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction.methodInvoke(DefaultInteraction.java:80) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.callMethod(MethodExecutor.java:44) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:31) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.findAndInvoke(MethodExecutor.java:57) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.FixtureMethodExecutor.execute(FixtureMethodExecutor.java:20) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.getMethodExecutionResult(StatementExecutor.java:126) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.call(StatementExecutor.java:104) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.instructions.CallInstruction.executeInternal(CallInstruction.java:35) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:29) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:83) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:84) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:77) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:56) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:42) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:186) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:194) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:156) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:77) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
        at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:57) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
```

Comment: paul, did you configure build path perfectly with your IDE?

Comment: I am not using any IDE. I open `fitnesse-standalone.jar` in `cmd`. It gives `fitnesse` front page on `localhost`, from there I click `Test` and tests runs.

Answer (score 0):

RestFixture depends - for it's HTTP interactions with the System under test - on RestClient (https://github.com/smartrics/RestClient), which in turns depends on Apache HTTP Client 3.1 (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

The exception you see is caused by having added to your classpath "`httpclient-4.0.jar`" (which doesn't contain the missing class).

You can fix the  problem (and avoid any other class not found issue) by adding all jars provided in the RestFixture bundle `smartrics-RestFixture-4.0-bin.zip` for example available from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/smartrics/restfixture/smartrics-RestFixture/4.0/